# Coerce list of lists to data_frame, but maintain *some* elements in list columns

Tags: r, tibble

I am looking for a way to reliably coerce a list structure to a `data.frame` or `tibble` while maintaining one or more columns as list columns. Consider the following list structure:

```
d = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1.5*(1:10) + rnorm(10))
ex = list(label = "A", number = 1L, model = lm(y ~ x, data = d))
```

This does not work as intended:

```
lapply(ex, as_data_frame) %>% bind_rows()
```

Because the `lm` object in the "model" column gets vectorized in the conversion. However, wrapping the model in `list` gets the expected result:

```
ex2 = list(label = "A", number = 1L, model = list(lm(y ~ x, data = d)))
as_data_frame(ex2)
```

Unfortunately, I have a use case where I don't know beforehand whether a given column is a list or not. I am working with a function that outputs something like this:

```
ex3 = list(
  list(label = "A", number = 1L, model = lm(y ~ x, data = d)),
  list(label = "B", number = 1L, model = lm(y ~ x + 0, data = d))
)
# won't work properly
lapply(ex3, as_data_frame) %>% bind_rows()
```

Is there a way to prevent `data_frame` from vectorizing an object in the transformation to a `tibble`? If not, what alternative approach could I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
ex3 %>% 
 transpose %>% 
 map_if(~all(lengths(.) == 1), unlist) %>% 
 as_tibble
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  label number model   
#   <chr>  <int> <list>  
#1 A          1 <S3: lm>
#2 B          1 <S3: lm>
```

For the first case, make the 'model' as a `list` and then use `as_tibble`

```
ex$model <- list(ex$model)
as_tibble(ex)
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of `transpose` in your answer?

Comment: `transpose` will get the elements of the same names together

Comment: I see, interesting. Your solution reshapes the list and then `unlist`s the atomic elements, whereas the other solution `list`s non-atomic elements. Benchmarking shows your method is significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

One option that I'm not super happy with, but might help guide the discussion:
Check the types of each element the list structure and wrap them in a list if they are non-atomic or have more than 1 element:

```
listify = function(x) {
  if(length(x) > 1L || !is.atomic(x))
    list(x)
  else
    x
}
lapply(ex3, function(x) as_data_frame(lapply(x, listify))) %>% bind_rows()
```

Not sure how robust this is, and probably slow too.

---

**EDIT**

Another option, which I found in an [old dplyr issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2493) linked from a [related tibble issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/205):

```
library (purr)
ex3 = map(ex3, ~ as_list(extract(., "model"))
```

However, this only works on one "column" at a time, and also requires you to know the name of the column you want to wrap in a list.

If `as_tibble_row` gets implemented, that will probably be the preferred solution.