# Add list to each row in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to add a list to each row of a dataframe.

```
# DATA
> df <- tibble(ID = 1:6, x = letters[1:6])

# A tibble: 6 x 2
     ID x    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c    
4     4 d    
5     5 e    
6     6 f
```

It's easy to add a single value.

```
df$new.col <- "boo"

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID x     new.col
  <int> <chr> <chr>  
1     1 a     boo    
2     2 b     boo    
3     3 c     boo    
4     4 d     boo    
5     5 e     boo    
6     6 f     boo
```

Adding more than one value isn't straightforward.

Instead of adding the list to each row (as above), the contents of the list are applied to the entire column. This is not very intuitive:

```
df$my.lists <- list("boo", "bah")
df %>% unnest()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID x     my.lists
  <int> <chr> <chr>   
1     1 a     boo     
2     2 b     bah     
3     3 c     boo     
4     4 d     bah     
5     5 e     boo     
6     6 f     bah
```

...and neither...

```
df$my.lists <- c("boo", "bah")
df %>% unnest()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID x     my.lists
  <int> <chr> <chr>   
1     1 a     boo     
2     2 b     bah     
3     3 c     boo     
4     4 d     bah     
5     5 e     boo     
6     6 f     bah
```

my desired result would have a list in each row, as below:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID x     my.lists
  <int> <chr> <chr>   
1     1 a     <list [2]>    
2     2 b     <list [2]>
3     3 c     <list [2]>
4     4 d     <list [2]>
5     5 e     <list [2]>
6     6 f     <list [2]>
```

Comment: Try `df$my.lists <- list(list("boo", "bah"))`. Also, see [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/205) on the `tibble` repo.

Comment: Regarding the intuitiveness of this result, a list is just a fancy vector - `is.vector(list(1,2))` - so doing `df$x <- list(1,2)` is analogous to doing `df$x <- c(1,2)` , with all the same recycling rules. As mikeck shows, you need to make your input a length 1 vector so `df$x <- list(list(1,2))` works the same as `df$x <- 1` , with the single value/list repeated for every row.

Comment: @mikeck: Please put this in an answer, so I can credit you. Thanks to you both for the valuable lesson.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue that probably all `tidyverse` users run into at some time or another (for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701573/coerce-list-of-lists-to-data-frame-but-maintain-some-elements-in-list-columns) I posted a while back). Basically, `tibble` tries to make clever assumptions about how to deal with column-binding vectors or lists with different lengths. These assumptions are consistent with how the rest of R does vector recycling, but you generally *don't* want to use the same recycling logic with list columns.

The solution is to wrap your list in another list, so that `tibble` interprets the new value as a single element and repeats it, rather than recycling the *elements* of the list.

```
df$my.lists <- list(list("boo", "bah"))
```

The preferred approach may change in the next release of `tibble`, see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/205) for more info.

Comment: Is there an alternative approach to unnesting twice when expanding the values? As `df %>% unnest() %>% unnest()`

Comment: @Nettle it depends on your input. If you were to do `df$my.lists <- list(c("boo", "bah"))` then you only need one `unnest` as `tidyr` recognizes that the individual elements of the list column are vectors. But if you can't use `c` (e.g. because the elements of the inside list are different types) then you need the double `unnest`.